# Android: OnPreferenceClickListener not responding

Tags: android, android-fragments

The OnPreferenceClick is not being called when the preference is pressed. The code is able to find the preference, but will not respond the the button press.

**Settings.Java**

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static class MiDeviceEdit extends PreferenceFragment   {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.mi_device_edit);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Preference devices[] = new Preference[5];

        devices[0] =  findPreference("deviceOne");

        devices[0].setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                System.out.print("On Press Worked");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**mi_device_edit.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<Preference
    android:key="deviceOne"
    android:title="@string/mi_device_one"
    >
</Preference>
```

First time asking a question. Hope I followed the rules and this was enough info! Thank You!

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. It seems the click was working, but the System.out message does not work in that function.  I have finally discovered the Log function, which produced the desired results. Thank You!

Comment: You should "answer" your own question if you think it will help others, or just delete the question.